Formula complexity of $n = 0 \pmod m$
Given two $k$-bits numbers $n$ and $m$, how large is a Boolean formula that computes whether $n = 0\pmod m$?

Divisibility is decidable in uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$, hence in uniform $\mathrm{NC}^1$, i.e., it has DLOGTIME-uniform Boolean formulas of size $k^{O(1)}$. I'm not aware of an explicit upper bound on the exponent being given in the literature, though in principle it can be estimated by inspection of the (rather complicated) division/iterated multiplication algorithms due to Hesse, Allender, and Barrington, or even the earlier nonuniform construction by Beame, Cook, and Hoover.

Thanks, much precise as usual!
